# Xamarin iOS global styles

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm developing Xamarin iOS app.

Is it possible to create global styles (e.g. for buttons) in Xamarin iOS apps like in Xamarin Android apps?

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a page in the Xamarin documentation specifically for Global Styles, I'd suggest searching the docs before posting here next time as you'll get a quicker answer :) https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/application/

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn, the author didn't mention a usage of xamarin forms.

Comment: @EvZ fair point, I must have missed that, my bad and thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Apple provides [Appearance API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance) that you could use for this purpose.
There is a [nice article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/ios-ui/introduction_to_the_appearance_api/) about it on official Xamarin developer portal.

The idea behind it is that you could use static methods on the controls to set a desired appearance, for example:

```cs
UIButton.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.LightGray;
UIButton.Appearance.SetTitleColor(UIColor.FromRGB(0,127,14), UIControlState.Normal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a control set common theme in that.

For example

```
public class CustomTextField : UITextField
{
    public UIView RightViewEnabled
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public UIView RightViewDisabled
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override CoreGraphics.CGRect LeftViewRect(CoreGraphics.CGRect forBounds)
    {
        var rect = base.LeftViewRect(forBounds);
        rect.X += 10;
        //rect.Y -= 2;
        return rect;
    }

    public override CoreGraphics.CGRect RightViewRect(CoreGraphics.CGRect forBounds)
    {
        var rect = base.RightViewRect(forBounds);
        rect.X -= 10;
        return rect;
    }

    public override CoreGraphics.CGRect TextRect(CoreGraphics.CGRect forBounds)
    {
        var rect = base.TextRect(forBounds);
        if (LeftView != null)
            rect.X += 5;
        if (RightView != null)
            rect.Width -= 10;
        return rect;
    }


    public override CoreGraphics.CGRect EditingRect(CoreGraphics.CGRect forBounds)
    {
        var rect = base.EditingRect(forBounds);
        if (LeftView != null)
            rect.X += 5;
        //if (RightView != null)
        //    rect.X -= 10;
        return rect;
    }

    public override bool Enabled
    {
        get 
        {
            return base.Enabled;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Enabled = value;
            if (value)
            {
                if (RightViewEnabled != null)
                    RightView = RightViewEnabled;
                base.TextColor = _textColor;
            }
            else
            {
                if (RightViewDisabled != null)
                    RightView = RightViewDisabled;
                if (TextColorDisabled != null)
                    base.TextColor = TextColorDisabled;
            }
        }
    }

    public UIColor TextColorDisabled
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private UIColor _textColor;

    public override UIColor TextColor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.TextColor;
        }
        set
        {
            _textColor = value;
            base.TextColor = value;
        }
    }

    public Guid ValueId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override bool CanPerform(ObjCRuntime.Selector action, Foundation.NSObject withSender)
    {
        if (action == new Selector("paste:") || action == new Selector("cut:") || action == new Selector("copy:")
             || action == new Selector("select:") || action == new Selector("selectAll:") || action == new Selector("delete:") || action == new Selector("_promptForReplace:")
             || action == new Selector("_transliterateChinese:") || action == new Selector("_showTextStyleOptions:") || action == new Selector("_define:") || action == new Selector("_addShortcut:")
             || action == new Selector("_accessibilitySpeak:") || action == new Selector("_accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection:") || action == new Selector("_accessibilityPauseSpeaking:") || action == new Selector("makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:")
             || action == new Selector("makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:") || action == new Selector("_share:"))
            return false;
        else
            return base.CanPerform(action, withSender);
    }
}
```